# functional React components with TypeScript using generic props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to understand and solve my own problem which is related to react components generic props.I have taken this code example from this article [functional React components with TypeScript using generic props](https://wanago.io/2020/03/09/functional-react-components-with-generic-props-in-typescript/).
Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce the same in the Codesandbox and I get a ts error.
Link to sandbox - [link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-chebyshev-9djte?file=/src/index.tsx)

Typescript can't infer the right type for Tablle objects and throws an error

> Property 'title' does not exist on type 'ObjectType'

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but seems like I just copied a part of the code from the article and it doesn't work.

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';


interface Props<ObjectType> {
  objects: ObjectType[];
  properties: {
    key: keyof ObjectType,
    title: string,
  }[];
}

function Table<ObjectType,>(
  { objects, properties }: PropsWithChildren<Props<ObjectType>>,
) {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {
          objects.map(object => (
            <div>{object.title}</div>
          ))
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

const PostsPage = () => {
  const posts = [{id: 1, title: 'fsdf'}, {id: 2, title: '222fsdf'}];
  return (
    <div>
      <Table
         objects={posts}
         properties={[
           {
              key: 'title',
              title: 'Title'
            },
         ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<PostsPage />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually generics are expressed as `<T>`, which can be any type. `T` or (`ObjectType`) doesn't guarantee anything about what properties it may have. If you try to access a property that TypeScript doesn't know about, it will complain.

If you want to assert that `ObjectType` has a title property, you can do

```
type WithTitle = {
  title: string;
};

<ObjectType extends WithTitle>
```

Or create a one-off object

```
<ObjectType extends { title: string }>
```

Though you can use `<ObjectType>` as your template, I'd recommend sticking with `<T>`, as it is the common convention, and you won't be tempted to think that `T` is a defined type, while you may be looking around for the definition of `ObjectType`.